# Inner join three tables out of which one is not connected with other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `client_invoices ,contract_additional_info and contract` out of which
`client_invoices` is connected with `contract_additional_info`  and `contract_additional_info` is connected with `contract table` .

`contract` table and `client_invoices` table don't have any relations.

[image]

Now I am running following query

```
SELECT   client_invoices.markup_type,
         client_invoices.supplier_invoice_number, 
         client_invoices.client_payment_req_id,
         client_invoices.net_amount,
         client_invoices.markup_value,
         client_invoices.net_qty,
         client_invoices.markup_value,
         contract.clientId as buyerClientId,
         contract_additional_info.buyer_contract_id as contract_id
FROM client_invoices
INNER JOIN contract_additional_info ON contract_additional_info.contract_id =client_invoices.contract_id
INNER JOIN contract ON contract_additional_info.buyer_contract_id = contract.id  
WHERE  client_invoices.status=3 ;
```

It is giving me duplicate records ,how to fix the query such that it only gives unique records (`unique client_invoice.supplier_invoice_number`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT`? This should give you only unique records.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try a GROUP BY with the columns that are identified as primary items to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by assuming that one of the joins is returning multiple results which causes the duplicates:

Either multiple contract_additional_info returned for each invoice or multiple contracts for each contract_additional_info.

Based on their names, I would say the former is causing this.  If this is true, ask yourself if that is correct.  Maybe the database structure is your problem.

If it is correct and you can have the same invoice for multiple contract_additional_info entries, then GROUP BY the column(s) you expect to be unique (check that they are unique at the column level as well). E.g. supplier invoice number and/or client_invoices.contract_id.

You could also join with a SELECT DISTINCT sub query from the contract_additional_info table.